# Show that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^qx^n$ is absolutely convergent, and that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $n^qx^n = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, absolute-convergence

I'm having trouble with proving the following for my math study:

Let $x$ be a real number with $|x| < 1$, and $q$ be a real number. Show that the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^qx^n$ is absolutely convergent, and that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $n^qx^n = 0$

I tried this:

$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^qx^n$ = $x + 2^q + 3^qx^3 + ...$
$= x(1 + 2^qx + 3^qx^2 + ...)$

So far, I don't know how I have to do this, I tried to apply the root test on this, but for that I would need to compute the lim sup of the series, so I thought that was not correct. Could you explain me how to prove this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I tried to apply the root test on this, but for that I would need to compute the lim sup of the series" It seems you are not applying the root test correctly so it would help if ([surprise, surprise...](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1241574/)) you showed what you actually did.

Comment: @Did Man, are you going to follow me for the rest of my life? I added a few more things I did. But, when I look at PENDU's answer, it was not such a bad idea of me to use the root test.

Comment: Sorry but once again, *what did you do to try to apply the root test*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in the root test you need to compute $\limsup_\limits{n\to \infty}|n^qx^n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Now $\limsup_\limits{n\to \infty}|n^qx^n|^{\frac{1}{n}} = \limsup_\limits{n\to \infty}|n^q|^{\frac{1}{n}}|x| = \left(\limsup_\limits{n\to \infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^q|x|=|x|<1$ because $\limsup_\limits{n\to \infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1.$ The result now follows from the Root Test.

Comment: Thanks mate, you are a big help