# Show that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^qx^n$ is absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am going through Tao's book and find myself struggling with problem 7.5.2:

> Suppose $|x| < 1$ and $q \in \mathbb R$. Show that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^qx^n$ is absolutely convergent.

I am trying to use the root test so I get that $$|n^qx^n|^\frac{1}{n}=(|n^q||x^n|)^\frac{1}{n}=|n^q|^\frac{1}{n} |x^n|^\frac{1}{n}=n^\frac{q}{n}|x|^\frac{n}{n}=n^\frac{q}{n}|x|.$$

By the limit laws and knowing that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $n^\frac{1}{n} = 1$, one only needs to prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $n^\frac{q}{n} = 1$. But this is the part where I am stuck.

I am aware that this has been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242380/show-that-sum-n-1-infty-nqxn-is-absolutely-convergent-and-that-lim), but the accepted answer just assumes
that $$\lim \sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^\frac{q}{n}=(\lim \sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^\frac{1}{n})^q,$$ with no prior justification. I have tried finding something in the book that helps me prove this, with no success.

I'd be grateful if you could give me a hint on how to show that $\lim \sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^\frac{q}{n}=(\lim \sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^\frac{1}{n})^q,$ or maybe suggest another path to tackle the main problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bothered me too, so after a lot of work I got this result:

**Theorem.** Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a convergent sequence of positive real numbers with positive limit $L$ and let $(q_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers converging to some real number $\alpha$. Then $(a_n^{q_n})_{n=m}^\infty$ converges to $L^\alpha$.

**Lemma.** Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a convergent sequence of positive real numbers with positive limit $L$ and let $\alpha$ be a real number then $(a_n^\alpha)_{n=m}^\infty$ converges to $L^\alpha$.

**proof of Lemma.** We may assume that $\alpha > 0$ (why?). By exponentiation and limit laws, we may also assume that $L=1$ (why? use the fact $\frac{a_n}{L} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$). So now we want to show that $a_n^\alpha \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, for that let $0 < \varepsilon < 1$ and set $\varepsilon' := \min(1-(1-\varepsilon)^{1/\alpha}, (1+\varepsilon)^{1/\alpha}-1)$. You should check, using lemma 5.6.9 and proposition 6.7.3 that this is well-defined and that $\varepsilon' > 0$. Now since $a_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, there is an integer $N \ge m$ such that
$$|a_n - 1| \le \varepsilon' \qquad \text{for all} \quad n \ge N$$
Expanding this inequality and using the definition of $\varepsilon'$, we get
$$(1-\varepsilon)^{1/\alpha} \le a_n \le (1+\varepsilon)^{1/\alpha} \qquad \text{for all} \quad n \ge N$$
Raising to the power of $\alpha$ and tidying up, we get
$$|a_n^\alpha - 1| \le \varepsilon \qquad \text{for all} \quad n \ge N$$
This shows the desired limit. $$\tag*{$\square$}$$

*Note that this lemma is enough to answer your question, but I'll prove the theorem anyway*.

**proof of Theorem.** We take three cases:

**The case** $\mathbf{L=1}$: Since the sequence $(q_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ is convergent, it is bounded by some number $M > 0$. Fix an $n \ge m$ then we have
$$a_n^{-M} \le a_n^{q_n} \le a_n^M \quad\text{or}\quad a_n^{-M} \ge a_n^{q_n} \ge a_n^M$$
based on whether or not $a_n \ge 1$ (see lemma 5.6.9(e)). In any case, we have
$$\min(a_n^{-M}, a_n^M) \le a_n^{q_n} \le \max(a_n^{-M}, a_n^M)$$
for all $n \ge m$. The rest follows from Lemma, the limit laws and the squeeze test.

**The case** $\mathbf{L > 1}$: Since $a_n \to L$ as $n \to \infty$ and $L > 1$, there is an integer $N_1 > 1$ such that $a_n \le L + \frac{L-1}{2}$and $a_n > 1$ for all $n \ge N_1$ (why?). Let $\varepsilon > 0$. So we want to find some $N \ge m$ such that $|a_n^{q_n} - L^\alpha| \le \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge N$. But before we get to that, let $\varepsilon' := \frac{\varepsilon}{L^\alpha + 2} > 0$ and use Lemma to find an integer $N_2 \ge m$ such that $|a_n^\alpha - L^\alpha| \le \varepsilon'$ for all $n \ge N_2$. Now by lemma 6.5.3
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(L + \frac{L-1}{2}\right)^{1/n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(L + \frac{L-1}{2}\right)^{-1/n} = 1$$
hence there exists an integer $M > 0$ such that
$$1 - \varepsilon' \le \left(L + \frac{L-1}{2}\right)^{-1/M} \le \left(L + \frac{L-1}{2}\right)^{1/M} \le 1 + \varepsilon'$$
(why? use the definition of convergence and the fact that $L + \frac{L-1}{2} > 1$). If we set $\varepsilon'' := 1/M > 0$ then we can rewrite the above as
$$1 - \varepsilon' \le \left(L + \frac{L-1}{2}\right)^{-\varepsilon''} \le \left(L + \frac{L-1}{2}\right)^{\varepsilon''} \le 1 + \varepsilon' \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Now since $q_n \to \alpha$ as $n \to \infty$ we can find an integer $N_3 \ge m$ such that $\alpha - \varepsilon'' \le q_n \le \alpha + \varepsilon''$ for all $n \ge N_3$. Now define $N := \max(N_1, N_2, N_3)$ and observe that
$$1 < a_n \le L + \frac{L-1}{2} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
and
$$L^\alpha - \varepsilon' \le a_n^\alpha \le L^\alpha + \varepsilon'\tag{3}\label{3}$$
and
$$\alpha - \varepsilon'' \le q_n \le \alpha + \varepsilon''\tag{4}\label{4}$$
for all $n \ge N$. From \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} (and exponentiation laws) we get
$$1 - \varepsilon' \le \left(L + \frac{L-1}{2}\right)^{-\varepsilon''} \le a_n^{-\varepsilon''} \le a_n^{\varepsilon''} \le \left(L + \frac{L-1}{2}\right)^{\varepsilon''} \le 1 + \varepsilon' \tag{5}\label{5}$$
Also using \eqref{4} and the fact that $a_n > 1$, we obtain
$$a_n^\alpha a_n^{-\varepsilon''} \le a_n^{q_n} \le a_n^\alpha a_n^{\varepsilon''} \tag{6}\label{6}$$
for all $n \ge N$ of course. In order to make $L^\alpha - \varepsilon' > 0$ and $1 - \varepsilon' > 0$, we assume without loss of generality that $\varepsilon < \min(L^\alpha + 2, L^\alpha(L^\alpha +2))$ (why does this not matter?). Combining \eqref{3}, \eqref{5} and \eqref{6} we get
$$(L^\alpha-\varepsilon')(1-\varepsilon') \le a_n^\alpha a_n^{-\varepsilon''} \le a_n^{q_n} \le a_n^\alpha a_n^{\varepsilon''} \le (L^\alpha+\varepsilon')(1+\varepsilon')$$
for all $n \ge N$. Finally since $0 < \varepsilon' < 1$ it follows that $0 < (\varepsilon')^2 < \varepsilon'$ so the above simplifies to
$$L^\alpha - \varepsilon'(L^\alpha+1) \le (L^\alpha-\varepsilon')(1-\varepsilon') \le a_n^{q_n} \le (L^\alpha+\varepsilon')(1+\varepsilon') \le L^\alpha + \varepsilon'(L^\alpha+2)$$
and thus
$$L^\alpha - \varepsilon'(L^\alpha+1) \le a_n^{q_n} \le L^\alpha + \varepsilon'(L^\alpha+2)$$
But $\varepsilon' = \varepsilon / (L^\alpha + 2)$ so we see that
$$L^\alpha - \varepsilon = L^\alpha - \varepsilon'(L^\alpha + 2) \le L^\alpha - \varepsilon'(L^\alpha+1) \le a_n^{q_n} \le L^\alpha + \varepsilon'(L^\alpha+2) = L^\alpha + \varepsilon$$
or i.e $|a_n^{q_n} - L^\alpha| \le \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge N$ which is exactly what we want.

**The case** $\mathbf{0 < L < 1}$: Set $b_n := 1 / a_n$ for all $n \ge m$ then by the limit laws, the sequence $(b_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ converges to $1/L > 1$. Thus by the second case $(b_n^{q_n})_{n=m}^\infty$ converges to $(1/L)^\alpha = 1/L^\alpha$. By the limit laws again, the sequence $(1/b_n^{q_n})_{n=m}^\infty$ converges to $L^\alpha$, but $a_n^{q_n} = (1/b_n)^{q_n} = 1/b_n^{q_n}$ so we are done. $$\tag*{$\square$}$$

PS: It turns out that Tao mentions the idea behind this theorem later on in chapter 9

> There is a stronger statement than Propositions 9.4.10, 9.4.11,
> namely that exponentiation is jointly continuous in both the exponent
> and the base, but this is harder to show; see Exercise 4.5.10 [Anlysis II]

Answer (score 1):

If $q\leq 0$, then $\sum |n^qx^n|\leq\sum |x^n|<\infty$. Thus we may take $a_n,q>0$. Let $\alpha = \limsup a_n$ and $\beta = \limsup a_n^q$. We will show $\alpha^q = \beta$. Indeed, $$\sup_{k\geq n}a_k^q = (\sup_{k\geq n}a_k)^q$$and letting $n\to\infty$, the thesis follows. It is elementary to prove the above assertion, namely that $\sup A^q = (\sup A)^q$, where $A\subset \mathbb R_+$ and $A^q = \{x^q:x\in A\}$.

An alternative approach is as follows.

Choose $n_k$ such that $\lim_k a_{n_k} = \alpha$. By continuity of $x\mapsto x^q$, we deduce $\alpha^q \leq \beta$. An analogous argument shows $\beta \leq \alpha^q$.

Comment: I have a few question about this. Doesn't $a_n$ need to be strictly greater than zero? If $a_k=0$ and $q<0$ you will have a problem. Furthermore, I don't see how your assertion is valid for $q<0$;  for instance, consider the sequence $0.5,1,1,1\dots$ and $q=-1$, then $\sup_{k\geq n}a_k^q = 2$ while  $(\sup_{k\geq n}a_k)^q=1$.

Comment: Sure, take $a_n>0$. And we can also take $q>0$. I've edited my answer, thanks @CoolJedi132

Comment: I see that $\sup_{k\geq n}a_k^q = (\sup_{k\geq n}a_k)^q$, it is also clear to me that $Lim\ Sup_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_k^q)=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\sup_{k\geq n}a_k^q) = lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}((\sup_{k\geq n}a_k)^q)$; however, I don't think this necessarily implies that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}((\sup_{k\geq n}a_k)^q)=(lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\sup_{k\geq n}a_k))^q$, which is essentially the same problem of the original question.

Comment: @CoolJedi132 It does, by continuity of the map $x\mapsto x^q$. On the other hand, see also the alternative solution I gave

Comment: Right, but we haven't even defined continuity on the text yet so I can't really use that tool.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $|x|<1$ and $q \in\Bbb R$, you have
$$
C:=\sup_{n\ge 1}n^q|x|^{n/2}<\infty.
$$
The estimate
$$
\Big|n^qx^n\Big|\le C|x|^{n/2}
$$
immediately implies the absolute convergence of the series in question.